# best methods to clear rax

Tags: assembly, x86-64

The popular method to clear rax is `xor rax,rax` (0x4831C0) but that operation affects the flag bits.

How to clear rax without affecting the flags?

For example:

```
mov rax,0 (0x48C7C0xxxxxxxx takes 7 bytes)
pushf + xor rax,rax + popf (0x9C31C09D takes 4 bytes).
push 0 + pop rax (0x6A0058 takes 3 bytes)
```

Are there more or better methods?

Comment: No, the popular method is `xor eax,eax`.  The instruction `xor rax,rax` is encoded as `48 31 c0` which wastes an extra byte.

Comment: If you really need to clear a register such that the flags are unaffected (typically an undesired feature), `mov eax,0` is the way to go.

Comment: Just to clarify what fuz is saying: Using `mov eax,0` really does clear all 64 bits of rax, and is (slightly) smaller than `mov rax,0` (5 bytes vs 7).

Comment: And while I'm thinking about it: If possible, consider using another register (say `rbx`) to hold the value of zero.  `mov eax, ebx` only takes 3 bytes.  Dedicating a register to hold zero might be overkill, but it's an option.

Comment: Never seen `xor rax,rax`, so I'm not sure why you think it is popular.. it's normally `xor eax,eax`, as it's 1 byte shorter.

Comment: `lea` from another register with a known small-integer value is an option for a 3-byte instruction.  e.g. `lea eax, [rdx-3]` if RDX was known to be 3.  Otherwise push/pop is a win for code-size vs. 5-byte `mov eax,0`, but only by 2 bytes and it's significantly worse.  See [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132981) for code-size optimization tips (many of which are harmful for performance; normally smallest is only a tie-breaker between otherwise-equal performance options.)